# Redshift SQL - Impute missing value: modify a table that only stores data when status changed to have daily data

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Suppose i have a table like below

```
ID  Status  Date
A1  S1      1/1/2021
A1  S2      1/4/2021
B1  S1      1/1/2021
B1  S2      1/3/2021
```

What I want my final table to be like

```
ID  Status  Date
A1  S1      1/1/2021
A1  S1      1/2/2021 --On 1/2, status remained the same as 1/1
A1  S1      1/3/2021 --On 1/3, status remained the same as 1/2
A1  S2      1/4/2021 --Status changed
B1  S1      1/1/2021
B1  S1      1/2/2021
B1  S2      1/3/2021
B1  S2      1/4/2021
```

How can I write a SQL query to achieve this?

And what if my table is like this, how can I impute those missing?

```
ID  Status  Date
A1  S1      1/1/2021
A1  NULL    1/2/2021 
A1  NULL    1/3/2021 
A1  S2      1/4/2021 
B1  S1      1/1/2021
B1  NULL    1/2/2021
B1  S2      1/3/2021
B1  NULL    1/4/2021
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have a calendar table or tally table?  Generating dates in Redshift is problematic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I do have a calendar table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a calendar table, you can do:

```
select i.id, c.date, t.status,
       coalesce(t.status, lag(t.status ignore nulls) over (partition by i.id order by c.date) as imputed_status
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     calendar c left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.date = c.date
where c.date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-04'
order by i.id, c.date;
```